# How get element iframe into iframe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, htmlcollection

How get element iframe into iframe?
JS HTMLCollectiion get 0 element return undefined?

```
<script>
    var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    var gbooking = document.getElementById('GbookingWidget');
    console.log(gbooking); //null
    console.log(iframe); // HTMLCollection
    console.log(iframe[0]); //undefined
    console.log(iframe.item(0)); //null
</script>
```

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Isp.png)
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MepmO.png)